# How to generate file with Spring+Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Is it possible to generate and save file with Spring+Thymeleaf in non-Web (non-JSP) app?

I have some mapped data and I need to generate output data to local file by template.

Comment: Actually, what Thymeleaf has to do with it? Is it possible to do some computations with C++ and Microsoft Paint?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
What precisely do you want to output? It is a templating engine. It has multiple uses. For example, you can generate email templates:
[Spring mail Templates](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html)
Also here:
<s>[Non web envirnoments](http://blog.iprofs.nl/2013/02/12/thymeleaf-create-page-templates-for-web-and-non-web-environments/)</s> [Thymeleaf: create page templates for web and non-web environments](https://iprofs.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/thymeleaf-create-page-templates-for-web-and-non-web-environments/).